# jquery mobile dynamically extended listview doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I've got a menu as listview in JQM. On every page it hould be normal, only on one of the it gets extended by 2 items. Now, I've been searching through Internet and nothing works. Things I've tried:

```
-location.reload()
-trigger('create')
-$("#menuList").listview().listview('refresh');
-$("#menuList").create;
-child.create
```

and maybe some more. Here's the code:
DOM

```
<div id="menu" data-role="panel" data-display="push">
<center>
    <a href="" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext"></a><br />
    <ul id="menuList" data-role="listview">
        <li><a data-rel="close" href="index" class="ui-btn">Home</a></li>
        <li><a data-rel="close" href="providers" class="ui-btn">providers</a></li>
        <li><a data-rel="close" href="seekers" class="ui-btn">seekers</a></li>
        <li><a data-rel="close" href="add" class="ui-btn">add</a></li>
        <li><a data-rel="close" href="logout" class="ui-btn">logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</center>
```

JS:

```
$( document ).delegate("#providers", "pagebeforeshow", function() {
function addMenuButtons()
{
    var ul = $("#menuList");
    //var hr = document.createElement("hr");
    //ul.append(hr);
    for( var i in buttons )
    {
        var name = buttons[i].split(',');
        /*var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.setAttribute("data-rel","popup");
        a.className = "ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow" ;
        a.id = name[1]+"Button";
        a.href = "#"+name[1];
        a.innerHTML = name[0] ;
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(a);
        ul.append(li);*/
        //a.create;
        $("#menuList").html( $("#menuList").html()+"<li><a data-rel='popup' class='ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow' id='"+name[1]+"+Button' href='#"+ name[1] +"'>"+ name[0] +"</a></li>" );
    }
    //$("#menuList").trigger('create');
    $("#menuList").listview();//.listview('refresh',true);
}

addMenuButtons();
});
```

buttons- object I made, doesn't matter here. Any ideas on this?? I keep failing trying fix this. When I F5 the page, the menu updates correctly...

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: 1.4.4, whatever, folks, I made it with php, but this not satisfy me because sooner or later I'll have to do this with js and this may be the only option in some cases. So I'm still waiting for any help/example...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/bkh6ncn9/ its working.

Comment: Yes it is :) Thank You! The issue seems to be in here: $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer... Weird however...

Comment: It looks like you aren't targeting the correct listview. If you add more details, it will be easy to spot the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use .enhanceWithin() on the parent of the changed widget.

```
 $('.parent').enhanceWithin();
```

Ref:
[**.enhanceWithin()**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/)

Comment: If you create a jsfiddle demo I'll take a look. Since the listview was changed call the function on the parent of the listview.